# Pages, Categories, and working with someone else's code

Tags: categories, pages, blog

I have working experience in Wordpress, and I have run into an issue that I can think of solutions for but I am not entirely sure of the best solution.

I am working in Wordpress on a site that is several years old, and I am a little confused by the site hierarchy. I ask here because the previous dev isnt available for comment.

The site is mostly a static site, with multiple pages of static content. All of this is arrayed in pages. However, the Blog portion of the site is set up as a category. It is the only section set up that way, and the blog posts do not appear on any other pages.

Is there a reason that jumps out to anyone as to why someone might do this?

Furthermore, I am tasked with redesigning just the blog section of the site (which is why this has come up), what would be the easiest way to make changes to the blog section (the entire page, including the header and footer)? I have set up a categories-slug.php page, but I wanted to make sure that I wasnt missing a better option (such as setting up a new theme, etc...).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the previous dev added the posts to the category to achieve a /blog/slug URL?

I don't know of any better way of doing the redesign, if you are wanting to keep the pages the design they currently are.

Are there any other posts other than the ones under 'blog'? If not, you can change the single.php file rather than category-blog.php.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. It looks like the blog was set up that way for no reason in particular. Multiple hands have been on this site, so I think it was just a decision somebody made with no other concerns.